# creating gradient on cell in a static iphone tableview

Tags: static, cell, tableview, gradient

do you know if it's possible to set a specific gradient for a static cell using UI Builder? Also accessing the cell from code would be fine. Unfortunately I cannot use the tableview delegate method for extracting the cell since this affect all the others.

thanks a lot

Claus

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution might be to use the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It actually gives the possibility of modifying a cell in a static tableview without affecting the other ones. Other solutions are more than welcome :)